# how to remove emoji in edittext password fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoji

When inputtype is used as textPassword, user was able to entire emoji in edit text. If I use both textpassword and textEmailAddress, then passwords are visible. Is there any easy way to achieve this without using textwatcher. The password field can allow other special characters also.

Please note that I am trying to remove emoji by setting the input type. I am not looking for solutions with regular expressions/textwatcher/filters. If the field is not password type I would have used textEmailAddress to avoid emoji option on keyboard

Comment: take digitoption in password filed

Comment: Use have to use textwatcher for prevent user by enter emoji in edittext

Answer (score 1):

This allow character only a to z and A to Z :

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Password `EditText` XML file

`android:inputType="textPassword|text"`

Look more about [input methods here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

Also, you can use RegularExpression to check whether your password is valid or not.